# Ipcamera serve to a multiple viewers

Tags: c++, ip-camera

I am working with an IPcamera with RSTP protocol, I am doing an embedded application in c++ and I need to run this application in two boards, and both need to show the video. But obviously when I try to connect both to the same ipcamera I get some decoding problems, and I guess that this is because I connect two device to the same ipcamera. I have been investigate and I do now how can I do this in a propertly way.

What possibilities do I have? Do I need a kind of server of something like this?

I hope someone have experience with this kind of ipcamera an application.

Thank you so much

Comment: RTSP server can support multiple simultaneous connections. Any more information will help others to help you better.

Comment: Hi Pragnesh thank you so much for your quick answer, well what I do is in my first application I recieve a "camera value" then I call a pthread in which I capture the image and show the video, and it works nice, but then I send the value to the second application which do the same like the first application. But after few second the second one start to appear problems. I hope I explain propertly, if you need more information let me know please

Comment: What is "Camera value", URL? If yes you can try to connect two VLC players on that URL. If VLC shows proper video then there is no issue from the server side.

Comment: Yeh the "camera value" is which camera should connect, I am doing this with c++ application and when I just connect with one is oke, but then with the second start the problems. I am going to try with VLC, I just need to download the program and try it right?Thanks